# How to make wordcloud from guided lda output

Tags: python, python-3.x, lda, topic-modeling

I have created topic model with some initial seeds using guidedlda package - https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA. It looks good. However now I want to see the frequency distribution and word cloud for each topic. How do i that?

I am accessing top 10 words in each topic like this,

```
>>> n_top_words = 10
>>> topic_word = model.topic_word_
>>> for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
>>>     topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-(n_top_words+1):-1]
>>>     print('Topic {}: {}'.format(i, ' '.join(topic_words)))
Topic 0: game play team win season player second point start victory
Topic 1: company percent market price business sell executive pay plan sale
Topic 2: play life man music place write turn woman old book
Topic 3: official government state political leader states issue case member country
Topic 4: school child city program problem student state study family group
```

However, how do i find the number of times each word appears in a topic and produce word cloud on that? Because I am not sure if this model captures the frequency of words.

Thanks in advance.